# I am receiving a Brackets Error stating "PHP runtime not found"

Tags: php, html, web, brackets

PHP runtime not found. Install the PHP7 runtime and update “executablePath” in PHP Preferences appropriately. This enables PHP-related tooling such as Code Hints, Parameter Hints, Jump To Definition and more. I have tried to find a solution to this problem but could not find any that has answers for a Mac. I am using brackets and wanted to implement a PHP contact page in my HTML template website. I tried using the code listed for json but it does not work and is said to be the solution for only windows.

Comment: Is your problem in a Editor? or on a website (web server software related)? seems to me like your missing PHP on your computer. Later versions of macOS doesn't have PHP pre-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not installed PHP7 on your Mac, which is why Brackets cannot find it. PHP doesn't come with Brackets, and you will need to install it yourself separately.

You can follow the instructions [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.packages.php) to install it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have installed the latest version of PHP8.1 and wanted to switch it to an older version to have access to PHP7. However I Cannot brew uninstall or unlink php in my mac to PHP7 as I receive "% brew link php@7
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7"

Comment: @AlinFarah I would first check if Brackets works with PHP8.1 as well. Since PHP is great at backwards compatibility, it will likely just work. Brackets gets a bit less updates these days, so the 'PHP7' might just be outdated.